# Dynamically added element will not delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does `.mydiv img` not get removed in this codeblock?

```
$( document ).on( "click", '.onhover', function() {
    $('.mydiv img').remove();
    var clone = $('.onhover').clone();
    $('.mydiv').append(clone);
});
```

Also I should add that each image's `src` is *base64*, not sure if that is the problem.

---

EDIT: `.onhover` html

```
<img class="onhover" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAKT2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AUkSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89+bN/rXXPues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHAAEAizZCFz/SMBAPh+PDwrIsAHvgABeNMLCADATZvAMByH/w/qQplcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUAEB6jkKmAEBGAYCdmCZTAKAEAGDLY2LjAFAtAGAnf+bTAICd+Jl7AQBblCEVAaCRACATZYhEAGg7AKzPVopFAFgwABRmS8Q5ANgtADBJV2ZIALC3AMDOEAuyAAgMADBRiIUpAAR7AGDIIyN4A...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" style="float:left; height: 100%; position: relative; width: 55px; margin-right: 4px;">
```

Comment: There is some log or error on console? Have you inpected the code with debug tools?

Comment: What's the content for `.onhover` ? Post your html please

Comment: Thanks added the html for `.onhover`

Comment: I've never seen this syntax `$( document ).on( "click", '.onhover', function() {...});` before, I always use `$('.onhover').on('click', function (){...});`

Can that be the problem?

Comment: There is no error in the console strangely. If it is the same img (ie has the same `base64` encoding, the code seems to work), otherwise if it is different image the img is not removed

Comment: @paolo - That's event delegation. Checkout on()'s docs.

Comment: @NickB actually, what do you want to achieve? You replace something with a 100% copy of itself. Seems unnecessary for me.

Comment: @paolo an image preview location. A bunch of images in a gallery clicking on one places it in a larger container. Need to remove the previous image on click though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want.

```
$('.onhover').on("click", function () {
    $('.mydiv').html($(this).clone());
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/paoloposo/kqukymy3/2/)

**EDIT:**

I have an updated code here that supports thumnails and full-size images for the single view:

http://jsfiddle.net/paoloposo/kqukymy3/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone before you remove.  You can also make sure you are removing the thing being clicked:

```
$( document ).on( "click", '.onhover', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        $clone = $this.clone();

    $this.remove();
    $parent.append( $clone );
});
```

EDIT: Assuming that `.mydiv` is somewhere else on the page... maybe something like this:

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <img class="onhover" src="img1.jpg" />
    <img class="onhover" src="img2.jpg" />
    <img class="onhover" src="img3.jpg" />
</div>
```

...then you would want to use the following code instead:

```
var $mydiv = $('.mydiv');
$( document ).on( "click", '.onhover', function() {
    var $clone = $(this).clone().removeClass('onhover');
    $mydiv.empty().append( $clone );
});
```

Comment: Oh my gosh explain the downvotes! As soon as he has 2 items with `.onhover` or `.mydiv` he would end up cloning and appending all of them to one another.  My code makes sure he's dealing *only* with the one being clicked.